# Why is this div not inline with the others when there's plenty of space for it?

Tags: html, css, css-float

Here's the fiddle of my project https://jsfiddle.net/Optiq/65rddhu4/

If you look at the label on the right side that says "Strongest" you'll notice that it sits beneath even the div it's contained within.  I initially had the div narrower in width but even as I extend it out it still stays on the bottom.

I know a way to work around it is to use CSS to add a position attribute to force it to where I want it to be, but from my experience with positioning things like that it may look right in one browser but may be 400px away in a different browser.  Why is this occurring?

Here's the HMTL

```
                <div class="texfrm_o" style="height:128px;">
                <div class="texfrm_i" style="width:99%; height:128px; margin:auto;"><br />
                    <label class="label_02" style="width:77%; text-align:center; margin:auto;">Generating Ideas</label><br />
                    <div class="anscont">
                        <div class="r_cont_lab" style="float:left; margin-left:4px;">
                            Weakest
                        </div>

                        <div class="radcont">
                            <div class="radbox">
                                <label for="q7a1" class="rad_lab">1</label>
                                <input type="radio" class="rad_buttn2" value="1" name="Generating Ideas" id="q7a1">
                            </div>

                            <div class="radbox">
                                <label for="q7a2" class="rad_lab">2</label>
                                <input type="radio" class="rad_buttn2" value="2" name="Generating Ideas" id="q7a2">
                            </div>

                            <div class="radbox">
                                <label for="q7a3" class="rad_lab">3</label>
                                <input type="radio" class="rad_buttn2" value="3" name="Generating Ideas" id="q7a3">
                            </div>

                            <div class="radbox">
                                <label for="q7a4" class="rad_lab">4</label>
                                <input type="radio" class="rad_buttn2" value="4" name="Generating Ideas" id="q7a4">
                            </div>

                            <div class="radbox">
                                <label for="q7a5" class="rad_lab">5</label>
                                <input type="radio" class="rad_buttn2" value="5" name="Generating Ideas" id="q7a5">
                            </div>

                            <div class="radbox">
                                <label for="q7a6" class="rad_lab">6</label>
                                <input type="radio" class="rad_buttn2" value="6" name="Generating Ideas" id="q7a6">
                            </div>

                            <div class="radbox">
                                <label for="q7a7" class="rad_lab">7</label>
                                <input type="radio" class="rad_buttn2" value="7" name="Generating Ideas" id="q7a7">
                            </div>

                            <div class="radbox">
                                <label for="q7a8" class="rad_lab">8</label>
                                <input type="radio" class="rad_buttn2" value="8" name="Generating Ideas" id="q7a8">
                            </div>

                            <div class="radbox">
                                <label for="q7a9" class="rad_lab">9</label>
                                <input type="radio" class="rad_buttn2" value="9" name="Generating Ideas" id="q7a9">
                            </div>

                            <div class="radbox">
                                <label for="q7a10" class="rad_lab">10</label>
                                <input type="radio" class="rad_buttn2" value="10" name="Generating Ideas" id="q7a10">
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="r_cont_lab" style="float:right; margin-right:4px;">
                            Strongest
                        </div>

                    </div><!--anscont-->
                </div><!--texfrm_i-->
            </div><!--texfrm_o-->
```

Here's the CSS elements at work with it

```
.texfrm_o{
    width:77%;
    /*background-color:#006;*/
    display:block;
    margin:auto;
    }

.texfrm_i{
    border-radius:11px;
    display:block;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#f9f9f9), color-stop(24%,#cecece), color-stop(67%,#cecece), color-stop(67%,#f2f2f2), color-stop(67%,#cecece), color-stop(100%,#828282)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    box-shadow:#383838 0px 11px 5.6px;
    }
.label_02{
    width:88%;
    height:22px;
    display:block;
    font-family:'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-size:12pt;
    background-color:#c9fffb;
    color:#489c7f;
    box-shadow:#8fd7d2 0px 0px 33px;
    border-radius:2.2px;
    }

.r_cont_lab{
    background-color:#CC9;
    width:88px;
    height:22px;
    font-size:8pt;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size:11pt;
    }

.radcont{
    width:400px;
    height:55px;
    background-color:#096;
    margin:auto;
    display:block;
    }

.radbox{
    width:40px;
    height:55px;
    float:left;
    display:block;
    background-color:#CC9;
    }

.anscont{
    background-color:#390;
    width:666px;
    height:55px;
    margin:auto;
    display:block;
    }
```

Comment: Please reduce your code to the minimum amount necessary to demonstrate your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Is this the result that you were looking for?

https://jsfiddle.net/Optiq/65rddhu4/
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sscyC.png

The change I made was moving your 
`<div class="r_cont_lab" style="float:right; margin-right:4px;">Strongest</div>`

block above the other div, this way it is adding it before just like you want (I hope)

Comment: ok I don't think it saved because it was the same way as I put it in, lol.  But I tried that and it did work, so thanks for that.  I'm just still lost on why it was showing up on the bottom though because essentially it should've stayed in line with everything.... right?

Comment: Well the main problem was the height of your radcont. It was forcing a height of 55px and when you put another div after it, it would show up on the same line height, You can do one of two things to fix it, put the div block in front like I demonstrated, or if you dont force a height of 55px on the radcont, your Strongest div will be back on the same line height as the Weakest div because you have no longer changed the height

Comment: by "not forcing the radcont to have height of 55px" do you mean switching it to auto instead?

Comment: yeah sorry or if it is not needed in the class css for the radcont, you can just not define it.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the following line in your fiddle.

And it **WORKED**
Check the following fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/dvwuxvaa/

I changed this 1 line in HTML part for weakest tab

`<div class="r_cont_lab" style="float:left; margin-left:4px;margin-right: 42px;">`

and changed css display property of the below

```
.radcont{
        width:400px;
        height:55px;
        background-color:#096;
        margin:auto;
        display:inline;
        }
```

let me know if it is helpful

Answer (score 0):

Just Remove the height:55px; of '.radcont' class,
Then your code of radcont class became as follows.

```
.radcont{
        width:400px;    
        background-color:#096;
        margin:auto;
        display:block;
        }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/65rddhu4/2/